# javascript not working for URL re-direct

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me with this script I'm trying to get working? I need a text box with a submit button, when a certain id is entered I need them to be re-directed to a certain site (below examples in the script are are yahoo, bing, etc).

This below is what I have so far, but the submit button doesn't show up and when the submit button is hit it doesn't seem to execute the script.

I just get a #? added to the url...  I'm working in opencart so I think part of the problem might be with opencart.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.getElementById("gobutton").addEventListener("click", function(event){
event.preventDefault()
var idmap={
REDDIT:"http://reddit.com", 
YAHOO:"http://yahoo.com",
BING:"http://bing.com"
};
id=document.getElementById("siteid").value;
if (id in idmap) {
alert("going to "+idmap[id]);
 window.location.href=idmap[id];
} else {
alert("invalid code ["+id+"]")
}
event.preventDefault()

});
</Script>
</Head>
<Body>

<form id="urllauncher" action='#'>
<label for="siteid">Site id</label>
<input type="text" id="siteid">
<button type="submit" id="gobutton">Go</button>
</form>

</Body>
</Html>
```

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: instead of `window.location.href=idmap[id];` use `window.location=idmap[id];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your script at the end of the body.

You are calling `document.getElementById("gobutton").addEventListener` too early, at this point the `button` is not yet present in the page DOM, so no event is attached to it.

Working code :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="urllauncher" action='#'>
            <label for="siteid">Site id</label>
            <input type="text" id="siteid">
            <button type="submit" id="gobutton">Go</button>
        </form>

        <script>
             document.getElementById("gobutton").addEventListener("click", function(event){
                 event.preventDefault()
                 var idmap = {
                    REDDIT:"http://reddit.com", 
                    YAHOO:"http://yahoo.com",
                    BING:"http://bing.com"
                 };
                 var id = document.getElementById("siteid").value;
                 if(id in idmap) {
                     alert("going to "+idmap[id]);
                     window.location.href=idmap[id];
                 } else {
                     alert("invalid code ["+id+"]")
                 }
             });
         </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

PS : try to indent your code prior to posting it !

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove that form tag ,it will solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need for it be of submit type and have a form at all

Just remove those and the event.preventDefault()